# Simcity 5 on the new Macbook 12" 2016 Model

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, games

I bought a Macbook 12" early April 2016 Model the other day and I really want to know if t will run Simcity 5. I tried running 'Can I Run It' but that doesn't work on Macbook's so I need some help to know if my Macbook can run the game before I purchase it. Thank you.

Simcity 5 Requirements:
Processor: Intel Core i5 or faster
Ram: 4GB
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 650M, 660M, OR 675MX OR FASTER
-These are just the recommended specs and not the minimum specs so these specs can be lowered.

Macbook 12" 2016 Model Specs:
Processor: 1.1GHz dual-core Intel Core m3 processor (Turbo Boost up to 2.2GHz) with 4MB L3 cache
Memory: 8GB of 1866MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 515

Comment: I would also mention that Simcity 5 is not optimised for Mac despite there being a mac version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel Core i5 is a significantly more powerful processor than Intel Core m3. I can't say for sure that it strictly *won't* work, but it will likely not be very smooth performance at all, unless perhaps you turn all the settings down to their minimum. I've heard even on MacBook Pro's without dedicated graphics (just intel HD) Simcity 5 performance is poor (lots of stuttering), and to the best of my knowledge the MacBook's graphics are not as strong as MacBook Pro's.

All that to say, I would not expect Simcity 5 to work very well on a Macbook at all.